# How to get Rails 3.0, MongoDB ( w mongo_mapper ) running happily on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, ubuntu-10.04, mongomapper

Hey all I just finished:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+3+-+Getting+Started#Rails3-GettingStarted-InstalltheRails3

But its not quite suited for ubuntu 10.04...

So how to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the fix ( $ = console ):

1. $ Rails new my_app --skip-active-record
2. paste http://pastie.org/3879397 into /config/application.rb
3. paste http://pastie.org/3879405 into /Gemfile
4. $ bundle install ... might say something about mongo failing
5. ( In Ubuntu ) System > Admin > Software Sources > Other Software > Add
   ... paste: "deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen"
6. $ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
7. $ sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen
8. browse to: http://localhost:28017/

after that it should look good!